# Can I render png image with React Fiber?

Tags: three.js, react-fiber

Everyone, I am using React Fiber and I just want to render png images, in more detail social icons, but it has backgrounds...
So here is source code link.
https://github.com/SmartDever02/Sportbase-Team-v2-THREE.JS/blob/main/src/App.jsx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtFsB.png)

How can I fix it?